# Die Form "fande" als 1. Person Singular Präteritum Indikativ (e-Epithese)

Tags: dialect, conjugation, preterite

Starke Verben haben in der 1. Person Singular Präteritum Indikativ keine Endung *-e*:

> ich ging, sah, kam, nahm, fand, half, blieb, ...

Die Ausnahme ist *werden*:

> ich wurde (*veraltet:* ward)

Nun höre ich gelegentlich von Muttersprachlern *ich fande* anstelle des standardsprachlichen *ich fand*.

1. Mich interessiert, woher diese Form stammt. Gibt es Dialekte, in denen sie üblich ist?
2. Gebrauchen Sprecher, die *ich fande* sagen, die Endung *-e* auch bei anderen Verben? Also *ich sahe, kame, nahme, ...*
3. Was ist die Geschichte dieser Form?

Da man nach gesprochenen Belegen nicht googeln kann, müssen schriftliche genügen. In Wikipedia-Diskussionsseiten findet man viele Treffer ([Korpussuche](https://pastebin.com/6mVTEBkS)):

> Hi - ich habe At the Drive-In erst einmal als Progressive-Rock
>   -Band eingestuft, da ich fande, dass der Musikstil der Band kein Punk ist.
>
> Hey Rudolfox Ich hab die erste Version der Interpretation geschrieben und fande deine Ergänzungen durchaus wertvoll und nachvollziehbar.

Dank @Marzipanherz konnte immerhin schon ein Name für das Phänomen gefunden werden: **e-Epithese**.

**Tonbelege.** 1. [Aufwachen #357](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUU0MSeoxSE&t=1h4m59s). 2. [Der Tag](https://ondemand-mp3.dradio.de/file/dradio/2020/05/11/110520_corona_und_protest_dlf_20200511_1700_131088bf.mp3#t=00:25:10) vom 11.5.2020.

Comment: Ich habe das noch nie gehört oder gelesen. Kannst du genauer spezifizieren, wo du das gehört hast (geografische Region, Radio- oder Fernsehsender)?

Comment: Mir geht's wie Hubert. Nie (von einem Muttersprachler) gehört. Muttersprachliche Italiener und Spanier machen solche Fehler gerne, wenn sie Deutsch lernen, weil ihr Idiom keinen Verschlußlaut am Wortende mag.

Comment: Mir geht es um Muttersprachler. Ich suche noch nach einem Beleg, aber wirklich nur nach einem, weil die Suche doch sehr viel Mühe macht.

Comment: Ich kenne diese Form im Sächsischen, und ich denke, es ist die einzige Ausnahme unter den starken Verben.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach ausgehend von Deinem Kommentar habe ich diesen Artikel über die [Akope](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apokope_%28Sprachwissenschaft%29) gefunden. David, das könnte für die Frage relevant sein.

Comment: Von dem Artikel über Apokope bin ich zu dem über [Epithese](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithese_(Linguistik)) gelangt. Im Frühneuhochdeutschen scheint diese Anhängung üblich gewesen zu sein, was auch erklärt, warum man bei Google Books leicht Treffer für "ich fande" in Büchern des 18. Jhdt. findet. Mich interessiert allerdings die Gegenwart!

Comment: @DavidVogt Ich hatte den Artikel so verstanden, dass _-e_ früher generell anhing, in den meisten Dialekten verloren ging und der heutige Gebrauch  ein Überbleibsel (vor allem im Obersächsischen) ist.

Comment: Bei der Apokope geht es doch um den Wegfall und nicht das Hinzutreten eines Lautes. Daher die Beispiele mundartlich oder umgangssprachlich *müd*, *hab* für standardsprachliches *müde*, *habe*. Epithese wäre das Gegenteil: mundartliches oder umgangssprachliches *fande*, *sahe* für *fand*, *sah*.

Comment: @DavidVogt vielleicht habe ich mich falsch ausgedrückt. Ich meinte: Die Standardsprache und die meisten Dialekte haben eine Apokope durchgemacht und das -e verloren, während in einzelnen Dialekten die Apokope ausgeblieben und das -e erhalten geblieben ist. Aber ich mag mich irren :)

Comment: Am Ende ist es wohl eine Frage der Perspektive: Lassen wir, die wir *fand* sagen, etwas weg, oder ergänzen diejenigen, die *fande* sagen, etwas? Der Wikipediaartikel nimmt schon die zweite Position ein, da sowohl im Mittelhochdeutschen als auch im modernen Standarddeutschen *fand* normal ist.

Comment: @Marzipanherz Ah, das ist sehr interessant. Vielen Dank!

Comment: Eine weitere Ausnahme von der vermeintlichen Regel ist auch _wollen_: _ich wollte_

Comment: Die Modalverben gehören doch zu den schwachen Verben (*-t* im Präteritum und im Partizip II)?

Comment: Ich kenne diese Form (genau für *finden*, aber ich meine, auch schon *stande* anstatt *stand* gehört zu haben) von Kindern bis etwa zehn Jahren (unabhängig von der Aussprache der Eltern). Ich habe es immer so interpretiert, dass die korrekte Form einfach erst später richtig sitzt und würde es wie »das gildet nicht« als Kindersprache sehen. Raum Hamburg.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich bin Muttersprachler aus dem sächsischen Raum, spreche zwar nur wenig Regiolekt, musste aber feststellen, dass mir beide Formen geläufig sind und sie sich für mich nicht falsch anhören. (Mir ist bewusst, dass es dennoch nach dem Duden standardsprachlich falsch ist) Besonders wenn ich mir die Form *fande* im obersächsischen Regiolekt vokalisiere, meine ich, dass diese Form dort häufiger anzutreffen ist.

Bei anderen Verben ist mir die Anhängung von -e nicht bekannt, eher die Weglassung.

Interessanterweise merkte ich, dass ich die Form *fande* nur nutzen würde, wenn ich es im Sinne einer Wertung (*beurteilen, befinden*) verwenden will, nicht aber beim *auffinden* oder *fündig werden*.

> Ich fande die Frage sehr aufschlussreich.

aber:

> Ich fand die Frage im Internet.

Weitere Belege für das Vorhandensein von *fande* in der Umgangssprache:

> Die Animationen waren auch, wie ich fande, wesentlich schlechter als im ersten Teil,[...][1](https://proxer.me/info/14110)

Oh - ein Gegenbeispiel zu meiner These:

> [...]und ich fande kaum noch Haare bei mir auf dem Bode.[2](https://www.amazon.de/gp/customer-reviews/R3SASM5S53MC8Y?ref_=fspcr_pl_sr_3_4_14_591282031)

Der selbe Effekt tritt auch beim Verb *sehen* auf. Jemand aus Nordrhein-Westfalen schreibt in einem Forum:

> Ich sahe gerade, dass Lennart auch Mitarbeiter der Standesamtsaufsicht ist oder war.[3](http://info4alien.de/cgi-bin/forum/YaBB.cgi?num=1122641590/15)

oder auch:

> Also ich sahe gestern ein unterhaltsames Spiel.[4](http://www.spiegel.de/forum/sport/sieben-tore-im-laenderspiel-klinsmanns-us-team-bezwingt-dfb-reserve-thread-91959-8.html#postbit_12880043)

Mit dem Verb *haben, gehen, sehen* in der 1. Person Präsenz verhält es sich ja genau anders herum. Dort hat sich umgangssprachlich, wie in dem Artikel über  [Epithese](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithese_(Linguistik)) vermerkt, das Weglassen der Endung -e durchgesetzt.

Deshalb wäre noch eine letzte These, dass es auftritt wenn man bemüht ist korrekt (oder Dialektsprecher Hochdeutsch) zu sprechen. Dies las ich in einem Korrektur-Forum indem über genau  [dieses Thema diskutiert wurde](https://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/113659/sbj/fande-oder-fand/).

Im 18. jahrhundert war diese Form wohl noch häufiger anzutreffen, was eine [Volltextsuche](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22ich%20fande%22&tbm=bks) in durch Google indizierten Büchern ergab.

Beispiel:

> Alles fande ich, was zur Equipage meines Schiffes vonnöthen war, nur an Tauwerck wolte es mir mangeln; allein, ich fande endlich Rath.

aus dem Buch "Der americanische freybeuter" von Robert Pierot von 1745

Comment: Der Code-Markup mit Gravis-Akzenten sollte nicht benutzt werden, wenn es sich nicht um Code handelt, denn er zerreißt den Lesefluss arg. Kursivsetzen ist wesentlich besser.

Comment: Die Beobachtung mit der Wertung kann ich bestätigen. Für mich bleibt die Frage spannend: Ist es eine Hyperkorrektur? Oder soll es eine besondere Betonung, einen besonderen Nachdruck ausdrücken? Oder haben wir es gar mit zwei verschiedenen Verben _finden_ zu tun?

Comment: Deine Beschreibung kann ich teilen und meine die auch schon gelegentlich gehört und auch selbst genutzt zu haben im ost-niedersächsichen bevor ich einige Jahre im thüringischen verbrachte

Answer (score 2):

@SeDav hat dankenswerterweise darauf hingewiesen, daß die Form *fande* in sächsischen Dialekten auftaucht. Ich wollte hier noch ergänzen, was ich in dem im Wikipediaartikel zur [Epithese](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithese_(Linguistik)) erwähnten Aufsatz zum Thema gefunden habe: Ulrike Imsiepen, "Die *e*-Epithese bei starken Verben im Deutschen", in: Karl-Heinz Best und Jörg Kohlhase (Hrsg.), *Exakte Sprachwandelforschung*. Göttingen: Edition Herodot, 1983, S. 119-141.

Die *e*-Epithese bei den starken Verben ist ein Sprachwandelprozeß, der sich nicht durchgesetzt hat. Im Verlauf des 17. Jahrhunderts erlangte sie ihre größte Beliebtheit, war jedoch nie obligatorisch. Man findet also auch in ihrer Hochzeit bei ein und demselben Autor Formen ohne *-e* neben solchen mit *-e*. Die Formen mit *-e* sind immer seltener als die ohne.

In einer Fußnote zitiert Imsiepen einen Autor, der festgestellt haben will, daß die e-Epithese  in thüringisch-obersächsischen Dialekten vorkommt. Das würde zu dem Beitrag von @SeDav passen.

Die Autorin hat mit viel Fleiß 28.000 Belege gesammelt. Davon wiesen 5.000 ein *-e* auf. Leider findet man in der Arbeit keine Informationen darüber, ob das *-e* bei manchen Lexemen (wie z.B. *finden, sehen*) häufiger auftritt als bei anderen.

**Nachtrag:** Eine im Internet zugängliche Quelle zur Geschichte ist Hermann Pauls *Deutsche Grammatik*, Band II, Teil III, § 155 [Link](https://archive.org/details/deutschegrammati02pauluoft/page/198). Dort heißt es:

> § 155. Als eine Angleichung der starken Konjugation an 
>   die schwache müssen wir es auch betrachten, wenn in der 
>   1. und. 3. Sg. Ind. Prät. der starken Verba ein *e* angefügt wird. 
>   Die Anfänge davon reichen bis in das 13. Jahrh. zurück, vgl. 
>   Weinhold § 374. Spätmhd. und anhd. sind solche Formen 
>   sehr üblich. Auch im 18. Jahrh. kommen sie noch oft vor. 
>   Schließlich sind sie doch wieder ausgestoßen, nur *wurde* hat sich 
>   behauptet und ist zur gewöhnlichen Form geworden, während 
>   das ältere *ward* auf die gewähltere Rede beschränkt worden ist.
>
> Auch *sähe* wird noch manchmal in feierlicher Rede im 
>   Anschluß an die Bibelsprache gebraucht.

Eine Quelle zur Verbreitung von *e*-haltigen Formen in neuhochdeutschen Dialekten habe ich leider nicht gefunden.

Answer (score 1):

Gerade hörte ich es wieder im Deutschlandfunk:

> Ich fande, dass...

Hört man gerade in Sendungen aus dem Kulturbereich öfters.
Ich find**e** auch, dass sich das heutzutage einem betulichen Gepflegtsprechenwollen verdankt.
Die haben dann das Gefühl, fand würde mit Apostroph geschrieben und sei zu umgangssprachlich.